# Fail to bind the options data in JS

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-jet

I want to display a select-only-one combo box using html+js.

What I want to show is like this:

[image]

But now I just get a blank drop down list like this：

[image]

The HTML code:

```
<div style="width:200px;height:100%;float:left;padding-left: 0px">
    <oj-combobox-one id="en" aria-label="en Select" options="{{ens}}" value="{{selectedEn}}"render-mode="native" style="max-width:20em" >   
  </oj-combobox-one>
</div>
```

The JS code:

```
self.ens = ko.observableArray([]);
self.selectedEn = ko.observable("a"); //Default to show
var en = ["a","b","c"];
self.ens(en);
```

Could you please help to find out where the issue is? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this page](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jsdocs/oj.ojComboboxOne.html#options) of the documentation. Each option requires the actual `value` (which is used by the JS file), as well as the `label` (which is what the user will see on the screen).

So you need to change your variable `en` to:

```
var en = [{value: 'a', label: 'a'},
          {value: 'b', label: 'b'},
          {value: 'c', label: 'c'}];
```

Comment: Thanks very much Ray! Well fixed! I shoud refer more to the JS doc next time.